# Memory design pattern for a large number of ephemeral small structs

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, design-patterns

I have a system that requires a large number of ephemeral signals to be allocated, processed, and disposed of after they have aged out. Each signal is a struct that is 12 bytes long - int clock + float size.
I have chosen struct rather than class to avoid the additional overhead of pointers to default constructor and destructor. The number of items I am looking to handle is of the order of 100,000,000 - that's 10^8. This will consume 1.2 * 10^9 (1.2 GB) so very containable on the heap but impossible on the stack.
These signals are generated for a future point in time that will cause the signal objects to age rather rapidly - within 10,000 - 100,000 clock cycles. Other objects in the system will have a queue of these signals that they process in ascending clock order and then dispose of them.
With this many ephemeral objects I need a low overhead memory management model.

First idea was to use an STL vector (priority queue in clock-order) to store the signals, but STL makes copies of the objects pushed into the container so that would double the storage requirements plus mess up reference pointers to the original signal objects. Besides, it's untenable to perform several hundred million allocations and deallocations on the heap.

Next idea was to use pointers to the signals to avoid object copying, but I'm still stuck with the overhead of allocation/deallocation for the millions of signals.

I like the idea of the priority-queue of pointers to the signals, as it carries low overhead and a copy of a pointer made by STL still points to object in question. What remains to be solved is how to allocate millions of signals, in rapid succession, enqueue the pointers to the signals, and dispose of them efficiently.

So far, the best design pattern I have come up with is to allocate a large array of slots - say 1,000,000 for holding unused signals, perform my own management of initializing the signals with the desired values and passing the pointer to the array slot on to the queuing and processing mechanism.

For this design pattern I would need to create a mechanism that "overloads" the C++ new function by allocating the next available signal slot, and "overloads" the C++ delete function to free up the slot in the array. When the array fills up I would need to allocate another array of unused signals to keep going. Once a signal delete indicates an array is now empty, I could then dispose of the moribund array.

The unique challenge for this memory design pattern is the constant creation, consumption, then disposing of millions of small signal objects.

Any pointers to fast, low-overhead memory design patters greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hmm, looking for a design pattern might be the wrong approach for the problem. Design patterns aren't _building blocks_.

Comment: _"...struct rather than class..."_: other than the default access (public or private), there is no difference a struct and a class.  A Ring Buffer comes to mind as a suitable container.

Comment: _"For this design pattern I would need to create a mechanism that "overloads" the C++ new function by allocating the next available signal slot ..."_ All containers can be provided with an _Allocator class_ as template parameter, also check out _in place `new`_. I don't think it's necessary to overload the `new` operator for this purpose.

Comment: First, one `int` and one `float` take 8 bytes, not 12. Do you signals ever come out-of-order? You've mentioned a priority queue, but if they are in-order - you only need an array (vector). Do you make any use of the `clock` or can you just drop it? You can avoid repeated allocation / reallocation by using large circular buffer - nothing to delete, ever.

Comment: Thank you for the replies - a ring buffer sounds like a viable approach to investigate. And Vlad, you're right Int + float is 8 not 12 (I originally had an embedded pointer in the signal but dropped it.)

Comment: I like the idea of a huge ring buffer - I can always keep moving forward and if I make it big enough, by the time it wraps around the old signals should either be aged out or pretty much worthless. This would also mean I don't ever have to bother to delete any old signals, just overwrite them at will. Many thanks team.

Comment: wrt struct and class being the same in C++, except for public vs private defaults, is there a good way to create a good old C-type struct as I really don't want to carry the burden of constructor/destructor pointers in every signal. Is there a way to coerce back to POD (plain old data) as I really don't want any member functions in my struct. Guess I could create a giant 2-dimensional ring buffer, but it would be more elegant to have a C-like structu.

Comment: "I really don't want to carry the burden of constructor/destructor pointers in every signal." @mlr94549 Someone else will correct me if I'm wrong; but I don't believe you carry that overhead. There will be a single place where they get defined, and that is implicitly referenced by way of the items being the type they are. You only carry this overhead when you make polymorphic types with virtual methods; then you get into the overhead of vtables.

Comment: It really sounds like you want a [memory pool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_pool).